# .net cache and its limitation in case of web farms?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-farm

hey. friends i dont know this question is really asked before or not ? but i need to know about .net cache and its limitation  in case of web farms and not in case of web farms.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asp.net cache can't be used in a web farm. It is an in-process cache.
You can consider [memcached](http://code.jellycan.com/memcached/) with [memcached providers](http://memcachedproviders.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're talking of the ASP.NET cache. The cache is per instance only, e.g. each web farm instance has its own cache (don't mix this up with session state, which can be stored in a shared way).

What kind of limitations do you mean?

Comment: data integrity and scalability is main problem.. but i dont know .. in advance or in detailed